# extension of premeasure to measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So I have been trying my hands on this problem for some time now and can't seem to figure it out. I need someone to help me out.

**Show that a set function on a $\sigma$-algebra is a measure if and only if it is a premeasure.**

Sketch of proof:

A set on $\sigma$-algebra is a measure if it is an algebra and given all subsets of the set,the union would still be in the set. By definition of the Caratheodory Extension Theorem, there exists a measure that can be extended to the premeasure. How to link that is my problem

Conversely, if it is a premeasure then a set function on a $\sigma$-algebra is a measure. Premeasure is an additive function of sets. Where do I go from here?